# grep search with regex

Tags: linux, grep, text-processing

how to find a line that contains exactly 3 "w", 5 "t" and no "v" with grep?

```
Input:
----------
aabbccddd4444
wccwwtttjjttuu
zzxxxwwwmmmnnnn

Expected output:
----------------
wccwwtttjjttuu
```

Because in "wccwwtttjjttuu" we have 3 "w", 5 "t" and no "v"

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
aabbccddd4444
wccwwtttjjttuu
wvccwwtttjjttuu
zzxxxwwwmmmnnnn
ccwwtttjjttuu
```

with `grep`, using extended regex and `-x` option match only whole line

```
$ grep -xE '([^w]*w){3}[^w]*' ip.txt | grep -xE '([^t]*t){5}[^t]*' | grep -v 'v'
wccwwtttjjttuu
```

with `awk`, not sure which versions support `{3}` regex construct. I tested on `GNU awk 4.1.3`

```
$ awk '/^([^w]*w){3}[^w]*$/ && /^([^t]*t){5}[^t]*$/ && !/v/' ip.txt 
wccwwtttjjttuu
```

with `perl`

```
$ perl -ne '(@w)=/w/g; (@t)=/t/g; (@v)=/v/g; print if $#w==2 && $#t==4 && $#v==-1' ip.txt 
wccwwtttjjttuu
```

- `@w, @t, @v` arrays contains all `w, t, v` characters respectively
- `$#w` gives index of last element in `@w`, so it's value is number of elements minus one

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne'/v/||y/w/w/d==3&&y/t/t/d==5&&print'
```